# Implementing a Custom ASPX Page That Uses a Custom Database

Tags: 2010, database, aspx

I know how to create custom ASPX pages and a deployment package, but I need to implement a custom ASPX page in SharePoint 2010 which uses its own custom database.

Please advise me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to do this is to configure **BCS (Business Connectivity Service)** to fetch data from external database to SharePoint and than work on the lists and libraries SharePoint.

Here are some articles to read:

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-getting-started-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

Hope it helps,